# Local Homeomorphism and Connected Set.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

> Let $\varphi:M\to N$ a local homeomorphism, with $M,N$ metric spaces. Given a metric space $X$, let $f,g:X\to M$ continuous, such that $\varphi\circ f=\varphi\circ g$. Show that if $X$ is a connected set, then $f=g$ or $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

An application $\varphi:M\to N$ is called a local homeomorphism when, for each $x\in M$, exist a open set $U$ ($x\in U$), such that $\varphi\vert U$ is a homeomorphism onto a open subset of $N$, and I know that a local homeo. is a open application continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $C=\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$. Suppose there is $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$. Then $C\not=\emptyset$. The idea then is to show that $C$ is both open and closed, and must therefore be all of $X$. That $C$ is open will use the fact that $\varphi$ is a local homeomorphism and that $\varphi \circ f=\varphi \circ g$. That $C$ is closed amounts to proving $C^c$ is open, which uses the same logic.

Edit: Let $x\in C$. Then consider $f(x)=g(x)=y\in M$. Then there is a $U\subset M$ an open neighborhood of $y$ such that $\varphi: U\to \varphi(U)$ is a homeomorphism. Now consider $f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(U)=W$, which is open in $X$ by continuity. Now let $z\in W$. Then $f(z)\in U$ and $\varphi(f(z))=\varphi(g(z)$, which implies $g(z)\in U$. Now, since $f(z),g(z)\in U$, $\varphi$ is injective on $U$ so $f(z)=g(z)$. Thus $z\in C$. So $x\in W\subset C\Rightarrow C$ is open.

Edit 2: Actually as pointed out, that $C$ is closed is actually trivial since $f,g$ are continuous and $X$ is Hausdorff. That completes the proof that $C$ is closed + open and we assumed it was nonempty, so $C=X$.

Comment: If C is a open set, $\varphi\vert_{C}$ is a homeomorphism, this implies that if $X$ is connected set then $\varphi\vert_{X}$ is a homeom?? thanks

Comment: No. The definition of a local homeomorphism says that for each $x\in M$, there is an open set $U$ such that $\varphi|_U$ is a homeomorphism. We cannot pick any $C$.

Comment: Sorry, I can not think how to answer this exercise

Comment: Edited with a quick solution. There might be a mistake since I did this hastily, but that's my basic idea of an approach.

Comment: Looks good. $C$ is of course closed because $f$ and $g$ are continuous (and metric spaces are hausdorff).